# Select multiple div elements by id with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe, foreach

I want to stop when you close a multiple modal video iframe.

This is my code.

**Rails**

```
<% @chapter.episode.each do |episode| %>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%= episode.id %>">
  <%= episode.name %>
</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<%= episode.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a id="close" class="btn-floating red right close"><i data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" title="Cerrar" class="right material-icons">close</i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="<%= episode.url %>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('div[id^="myModal"]').each(function{
        $("div[id^='myModal'] iframe").attr("src", $("div[id^='myModal'] iframe").attr("src"));
    });
});
```

When i close the modal, change the src of all videos.

Help me please.

Comment: The function that you're passing into each does not have parenthesis. Is that just a typo in your copy paste or could that be the issue? You have .each(function{ where you should have .each(function(){